# Get Ace Editor's content through the DOM

Tags: javascript, editor, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I am running some tests against a page using Nightwatch.js. I need to get the text content of an Ace Editor that's on the page, so that I can compare it against some JSON.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead, I hooked into the page's angular controller and grabbed the data I needed from there:

```
'is the Splash-Live schema set up correctly?': function (client) {
    var pageSplashLive = client.page.pageSplashLive();
    var code;

    login(client);

    pageSplashLive.navigate()
      .waitForElementVisible('@jsonButton', 15000)
      .click('@jsonButton')
      .waitForElementVisible('.ace_content', 10000)
      .api.execute("return angular.element($('.data-editor-form')).scope()['ctrl']['selectedData']['schema']['properties'];", [], function(response) {
          code = JSON.stringify(response.value);
          console.log(code);

          client.assert.equal(code,
            'json_goes_here');
        });
},
```